# How to reference a range of cells in UDF

Tags: c#, excel, add-in, user-defined-functions, excel-dna

c#, ExcelDNA, in my UDF, 
I want to pass a range of cells,  MyUDF(A1:A2)

I tried MyUDF(object param1), if I type in myUDF(A1:A2), the MyUDF is never called 
I also tried MyUDF(string param1), MyUDF(string[] param1) neither works.

What type of the parameter should be? thanks

Comment: Through your add-in where does the UDF live? (I'm not very familiar, but in VBA your UDF has to be in an independent module and not in a worksheet's or workbooks module). Is it in the wrong place?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The format `public static object MyUDF(object param1) {...}` should work fine, and your formula with `=MyUDF(A1:A2)` will pass in an object array with the values in those cells.

If you want to allow the argument to be a reference to the passed in range, you'd declare it as

```
public static object MyUDF(
    [ExcelArgument(AllowReference=true)] object param1) {...}
```

The extra attribute tells Excel to pass in the actual reference when called as `=MyUDF(A1:A2)` - the reference will be of type `ExcelDna.Integration.ExcelReference`, from where you can get the values or make further calls to the Excel API to get the address or anything.