# how to create excel custom function using C# visual studio where argument is range

Tags: c#, excel

i am trying to use C# xll to make a set of functions for excel. In one function i need to pass range as argument to the function. For eg. say sum of all cells in a range. how to achieve it

Answer (score 0):

The best way to interact with Excel from C# is to use ExcelDNA.  If you're using a "C# XLL" then there's a decent chance you ae already using it!  Then you need to decide if you want to work with a Range or array (it's the same distinction when writing functions in VBA). If you just want to read values from the sheet, you probably want an array, in which case something like this will work (assuming you've set up ExcelDNA correctly):

```
public static double SumFunc(double[,] values)
{
    int rows = values.GetLength(0);
    int cols = values.GetLength(1);
    double total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            total += values[i, j];
        }
    }
    return total ;
}
```

Note this will give a #VALUE! error if any of the passed values are not numbers.  If you want to use a true Range (actually an ExcelReference in ExcelDNA), you can follow the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358075/how-to-reference-a-range-of-cells-in-udf) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57214199/excel-dna-get-retrieving-values-from-cells-via-an-excelreference).